# C language cast void pointer by known size

Tags: c, pointers

Simple question, can we in c language cast void pointer by known size by unknown data type?

Consider this situation:

function **assertEqual**, which should get 2 pointers as arguments, dereference them and equal value. You can't of course dereference void pointer, but what if I know size of data, which the pointer point to? Can I create some dynamic pointer of known size but unknown data type? The function should looks like **assertEqual(void* expected, void* current, size_t size)**.

Comment: If you want to dereference something, you must choose a type. Equality is only defined for "known" types.

Comment: Most likely the function is a "functor" and the whole point of its existence is to provide a type-specific comparison - meaning that the function does know what type to cast to. Go read up of how the standard function `bsearch` works and it should all become clear.

Comment: I don't think you mean the size of the pointers, but the size of the objects you point to.

Answer (score 4):

You could cast the argument to `unsigned char*` and then compare the first `size` bytes (or better use `memcmp` which does that), but it is not guaranteed that it would do what you want in cases where there are multiple representations for a given value (think for instance to padding in a structure, a difference in the content of the padding is probably harmless but it would be detected by such an approach, there are other cases such as NaN value for floating point formats and technically that could happens for most primitive types).

Comment: `memcmp` never violates the strict aliasing rule, it is defined as doing a series of character comparisons

Comment: But structure padding is consider in function sizeof, so if I will pass size_t by sizeof of type, which I am asserting, then dereference should be ok.

Comment: @PavelParma: `sizeof` yields the **total** size of the `struct`, not of single fields. It includes any padding bytes. There also can be padding bits in single types. There is no guarantee two objects compare equal using byte-wise compares, except they are arrays of bytes (i.e. one of the character types)

Comment: @AProgrammer: Sorry, I always forget about 6.5p7, last item.

Comment: @Olaf, don't feel bad, it would not have been the first time I mis-remembered something or was confused by a difference between C and C++ (and the char vs unsigned char is probably a valid point)

Comment: @AProgrammer: That exception for `char` is imo a legacy. In ancient times the `mem*`-functions took a `char *` and `char *` was the "universal pointer". We now use `void *` for that, but for compatibility with old code (or programmers who don't want to go on - see the number of hardcore C90 programmers), `char` and `char *` still has this exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I create some dynamic pointer of known size but unknown data type?

As a general rule. no. You need to know the type to typecast the void pointer. e.g. float and int both have a size of 4 bytes but the types are not equivalent.

However, if you have equivalent types, then you can typecast to the equivalent type. e.g. on some systems int and long are both 4 bytes and are equivalent.

Comment: Neither `float` nor `int` is guaranteed to have a size of 4 bytes. They can have any size, starting from 1 byte.

Comment: It was an example to show that same size data can be incompatible. Also on the vast majority of systems float is 4 byte, and int is 4 byte for the most 32 bit systems.

Comment: The vast majority of systems does not have 32 bit `int`. And even **iff** they have 32 bit `int`, `sizeof(int)` can yield `1` (byte).

Comment: Really? Even if the int is 32b, sizeof should yield 1B? Why?

Comment: @PavelParma The C Standard does not put any restriction on the size of `short`, `int`, and `long`. What it does say is that `short` has to be smaller than `long`, and for `int`, it's either `int` >= `short` or `int` <= `long`. I may be wrong, this is as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple question, can we in c language cast void pointer by known size by unknown data type?

No.  Every pointer type has a specific type to which it points.  That includes `void *`, whose referenced type (`void`), is an incomplete type provided by the language.  There is no such thing as a pointer to an unknown data type, though in `void *` you have a pointer type that is is *interconvertible* with all other object pointer types.

On the other hand, it is valid to access objects of any type via a pointer to a character type (e.g. `char *`, `unsigned char *`), and one way to do that is via an lvalue whose type is an array of characters.  You could get something very similar to what you ask like so:

```
int assertEqual(void* expected, void* current, size_t size) {
    unsigned char (*ep)[size] = expected;
    unsigned char (*cp)[size] = current;
    // ...
}
```

That makes use of a variable-length array type as the pointed-to type: pointers `ep` and `cp` each point to an *array* of `size` elements of type `unsigned char`.  The size of that array type is `size`, so, for example, you will indeed find that `sizeof(*ep) == size`.  That is, you have a pointer to an object of the specified size, through which you are permitted to access the bytes of that object.

As others have already pointed out, however, what you ask is kinda pointless.  If you just want to compare two byte sequences without knowing what type of object they represent, then you can use `memcmp()`.  On the other hand, that is not safe as a general equality test because two objects with different byte sequences can nevertheless be equal when compared as objects of a given type.  This happens because many integer types are permitted to have padding bits that do not contribute to their values, and because floating-point representations are completely implementation-dependent.

Furthermore, `struct` and `union` types can contain padding bytes with unspecified, and not necessarily consistent values.  You cannot compare compound types with the `==` operator, but comparing the byte arrays constituting the representations of such objects does not necessarily yield the same result as would comparing the objects on a per-member basis.